# Tab bar appearing below the edge of the screen

Tags: iphone

I'm creating an application that, when the user selects a project in a table, displays a view with a tab bar at the bottom. I'm using this code:

```
- (id)init
{
 [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

 tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

 // Create all view controllers to be included in the tab bar
 SummaryViewController *summaryController = [[SummaryViewController alloc] init];
 ImagesViewController *imagesController = [[ImagesViewController alloc] init];

 // Make an array containing the view controllers
 NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:summaryController, imagesController, nil];
 [summaryController release];
 [imagesController release];

 // Attach them to the tab bar controller
 [tabController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

 [self.view addSubview:tabController.view];

    return self;
}
```

With the end result being the tab bar at the bottom appearing cut off around half its height. I'm guessing it's somehow related to the navigation controller at the top ([link to image](http://www.ixagon.se/tabbarproblem.png)).

Any help in solving this mystery would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you're adding the UITabBarController as a subview of another UIViewController. UITabBarController descends directly from UIViewController.

Instead of creating this view controller to hold it, you should just create the tab bar controller, configure it and push that onto your stack.

Comment: @Mark : creating the tab bar controller and pushing it onto our stack, will it work perfectly? will it autorotate?